# I cant see any text on Skype after update to ubuntu 15.10

Tags: skype

I recently updated ubuntu to 15.10. After the update I couldn't see any text in Skype! I tried reinstalling it

> sudo apt-get purge skype

Deleted the **/home/username/.Skype** folder

and reinstalled Skype but that didn't solve the problem.
[image]

As you can see from the image screenshot above, I can't event start it now as it is stuck on the **Terms of Use** window

I managed to login after restarting ubuntu but then it failed again
[image]

Comment: How did you install skype as in did you get the deb package from the website or did you add a PPA

Comment: I downloaded it from skype website http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64 skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb

Comment: do you have another desktop environment you can login to. ? try starting Skype from a another desktop environment.

Comment: @Waqleh , Could you try with `sudo rm -rf ~/.qt ~/.kde` . WARNING: `rm -rf` is a dangerous command, so write `sudo rm ~/.qt ~/.kde`, confirm  then add `-rf` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by switching from Unity to Gnome 3