# Broken interface in some (GTK2 ?) apps in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: skype, 15.10, interface, clementine

My question is linked to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695423/i-cant-see-any-text-on-skype-after-update-to-ubuntu-15-10) and expands on it a little. I experience the same behavior of Skype in a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10. More specifically, when I start Skype immediately after booting into Ubuntu, it will most likely work all right, but if I turn it off at some later time, it will more often than not show up with a completely garbled up and unusable interface such as here (copying the image from the question linked above):

[image]

I also observe the same behavior with Clementine. If I open it immediately after starting an Ubuntu session, it will most likely show up ok:

[image]

but if I start it some time into the session, it will often display a completely broken interface:

[image]

I suspect this may have something to do with the fact that both Skype and Clementine may be using gtk2, and my Ubuntu install does not have some libraries required for proper rendering of these applications, but I am at a loss of how to diagnose the problem more precisely and fix it. Perhaps you could help?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think that both those apps use qt, not gtk.

Comment: I must say that after a series of updates I am no longer experiencing the described problem. Hopefully it's gone away for good. Didn't have to reinstall Skype or Clementine.